Spring JPA : Sorting with pagination not working with JSONB column in Postgres
I'm trying to fetch records with Criteria API specification with PageRequest. It works fine if I try to sort by the parent property of the entity. But when I try to sort with nested property, I'm getting below exception. When I set the sort field as "division", records are being retrieved sorted by Division. But when I've set the sort field in Pagerequest to be "publicationSchedule.deadlineDate", I'm getting the exception.
For example: The entity looks like:
public class Publication {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "book_price")
    private String bookPrice;

    @Column(name = "division")
    private String division;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "JSONB", name = "publication_schedule")
    @Type(JsonBinaryType.class)
    PublicationSchedule publicationSchedule;

    }

And PublicationSchedule object looks like this (Note: PublicationSchedule is not an entity, but is a JSON prop of Publication table) :

public class PublicationSchedule{

    @JsonSerialize(using = TimeStampSerializer.class)
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private Date deadlineDate;

    @JsonSerialize(using = TimeStampSerializer.class)
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private Date publicationDate;
}

When I try to sort with direct entity property division, am getting the records sorted with division. But when I try to sort with deadlineDate from publicationSchedule, I'm getting below exception with the same specification.
Specification<Publication> specification = Specification.where(null);
<<Specification code generation here>>
Page<Publication> searchResults =
                publicationRepository.findAll(specification, pageRequest);



 ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet].log(175) - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Attribute 'com.elsevier.rpc.service.bff.entity.Publication#publicationSchedule(BASIC)' is not joinable] with root cause
org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Attribute 'com.elsevier.rpc.service.bff.entity.Publication#publicationSchedule(BASIC)' is not joinable
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.domain.AbstractSqmFrom.buildSingularJoin(AbstractSqmFrom.java:762) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.domain.AbstractSqmFrom.buildJoin(AbstractSqmFrom.java:697) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.domain.AbstractSqmFrom.join(AbstractSqmFrom.java:410) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.domain.AbstractSqmFrom.join(AbstractSqmFrom.java:69) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.getOrCreateJoin(QueryUtils.java:903) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.toExpressionRecursively(QueryUtils.java:799) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.toExpressionRecursively(QueryUtils.java:769) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.toExpressionRecursively(QueryUtils.java:765) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.toJpaOrder(QueryUtils.java:754) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.toOrders(QueryUtils.java:706) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:753) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:710) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:447) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]


an occured error

org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Attribute 'com.elsevier.rpc.service.bff.entity.Publication#publicationSchedule(BASIC)' is not joinable

mean that jpa try to join Publication table and PublicationSchedule table
so use @Embeddable and @Embedded annotation to clarify that PublicationSchedule is Value Type class
@Entity
public class Publication {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "book_price")
    private String bookPrice;

    @Column(name = "division")
    private String division;
    
    @Embedded
    @Column(columnDefinition = "JSONB", name = "publication_schedule")
    @Type(JsonBinaryType.class)
    PublicationSchedule publicationSchedule;

    }

@Embeddable
public class PublicationSchedule{

    @JsonSerialize(using = TimeStampSerializer.class)
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private Date deadlineDate;

    @JsonSerialize(using = TimeStampSerializer.class)
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private Date publicationDate;
}


Added these two annotations. But still getting the same exception.

does PublicationSchedule class have no argument constructor?

Yes, it's annotated with @NoArgsConstructor. And in my PageRequest, I've specified the sort by field as "publicationSchedule.permissionDeadline". Is this the right way to specify to sort by JSONB column property?

you should pass "publicationSchedule_deadlineDate"
like _ they joined with _ not .
for example
PageRequest.of(0,10, Sort.by(Direction.DESC,"publicationSchedule_deadlineDate"));

Changed it to "_" instead of "." ; Still getting the same error : org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Attribute 'com.elsevier.rpc.service.bff.entity.Publication#publicationSchedule(BASIC)' is not joinable
